# How to replace a archived root site to root site

Tags: url

So I have replaced my classic root site with a new modern root site. And now I need to replace the archived root site again as few WebJobs were running and used the old URL. According to our dev team, they can't change the URL in the jobs, and I need to make the archived root site our main root site again.
Would you please help me with this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you might not be able to swap your classic team site back.

[Quote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/invoke-spositeswap?view=sharepoint-ps):

> If the target is the root site at https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com then the source site must be either a Modern Team Site (STS#3) or a Communication Site (SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0) and the publishing feature can never have been activated on the source site.

You can't push (swap) a classic site to a root site since it's not supported.